# Mysql many to many table queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables cars, drivers, cars_drivers.

my cars table has two fields - carid and car_model

my drivers table has two fields - driverid and driver_name

my cars_drivers has two fields which are primary keys - carid and driverid.

I have 3 entries in my cars table

1. toyota
2. honda
3. kia

and my  drivers table has

1. bob
2. tom

What would my car_drivers table be like? Would I put any number 3 or less in carId and 2 or less in DriverId?

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
```

How would I make a query that will display 3 car models with random drivers?

I'm looking for something like

```
toyota  bob
kia     tom
honda   bob
```

ive been looking through some of the tutorials and im also not following how the joins work

Comment: Your cars_drivers table stores information about which cars are driven by which drivers.  If Bob drove a Kia, you would put (3, 1) into cars_drivers.  Joins aren't normally used for random data, but more to display relationships between data

Comment: [Information on how Joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 2):

JOINs relate pieces of information. An entry in car_driver tells you that the car is driven by the driver. If you just want to show a random driver, you don't need a join at all, just get all the drivers and pick one at random from the list.

Normally however databases relate information. For example, a person with the jobs they have had. You can't just put a random job next to someone, you use a JOIN to get the correct relationship

Something like

```
  SELECT * FROM jobs
     LEFT JOIN people_jobs ON jobs.jobid = people_jobs.jobid 
     LEFT JOIN people ON people.personid = people_jobs.personid 
     WHERE person.personname = 'Bob Smith'
```

would get you information on all the jobs Bob has had.

Where as

```
  SELECT * FROM people 
     LEFT JOIN people_jobs ON people.personid = people_jobs.personid 
     LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.jobid = people_jobs.jobid 
     WHERE jobs.job = 'Waiter '
```

would get you all the people in the database who have been a Waiter.

Answer (score 2):

Your schema should be such that the `cars_drivers` table has two columns (fields) which jointly form a composite primary key, and individually are foreign keys to the `cars` and `drivers` tables.

The `cars_drivers` table records which cars each driver 'can' or 'does' or 'wants to' drive.

For the given data, the values in the `carid` column should be in the range 1-3; the values in the `driverid` column should be in the range 1-2.  These constraints should be enforced automatically assuming you are using InnoDB storage (I reserve judgement on MyISAM, but I think it does not enforce PK-FK constraints).

```
CREATE TABLE cars_drivers
(
    carid      INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cars,
    driverid   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES drivers,
    PRIMARY KEY(carid, driverid)
);  -- Plus storage options as required ...
```

You select from the three tables with:

```
SELECT c.*, d.*
  FROM cars AS c
  JOIN cars_drivers AS j ON c.carid = j.carid
  JOIN drivers AS d ON d.driverid = j.driverid;
```

You can apply conditions on the join as you see fit.  Note that there's no particular benefit to displaying any of the data from `cars_drivers` in this join since the values would be the same as one of the values from each of the other two tables.

To get just the model name and driver name, you'd specify just those columns:

```
SELECT c.car_model, d.driver_name
  FROM cars AS c
  JOIN cars_drivers AS j ON c.carid = j.carid
  JOIN drivers AS d ON d.driverid = j.driverid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your tables look like this:

```
Table 1: Drivers
    id      Name
    1       Joe Bloggs
    2       Si Borg
    3       Anne Droyd

Table 2: Cars
    id      Type
    9       Honda
    8       Toyota
    7       Kia


Table 3: CarDrivers
    CarId   DriverId
    9       1
    9       2
    8       2
    7       3
```

Your query would be:

```
select d.name, c.type
from Drivers d
inner join CarDrivers cd
    on d.id = cd.DriverId
inner join Cars c
    on cd.CarId = c.id
```

Giving results:

```
Name        Type
Joe Bloggs  Honda
Si Borg     Honda
Si Borg     Toyota
Anne Droyd  Kia
```

The CarDriver table is basically linking drivers with the cars they drive; i.e. the first row in that table says that the driver with id 1 drives the car with id 9.

Comment: Really was easy to understand. +1